# Passing empty json_encode array to JQuery

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, json

I have the following json encoded array which I pass to JQuery as follows, and everything works fine when when there are elements in the array. However, there are times when the array might be empty depending
upon a users selections, and that is where my script breaks down:

```
PHP
$myleaderarray =  [{"Week_count":"3","Userid":"102","Username":"gsd555","MedCondPrimary":"Diabetes"},{"Week_count":"0","Userid":"216","Username":"gsd3","MedCondPrimary":"Cardiac Respiratory"}]
$count = count($myleaderarray);   //1

JQ
var myleaderarray = <?php echo $myleaderarray; ?>; // this passes the       array as expected
console.log(myleaderarray.length); //2
```

This is what I see in the console when the json_encoded array is empty

```
JQ
var myleaderarray = ;
"Unexpected token ';'"
```

I can't seem to test for this error in JQ so must I do this on the server-side, or
am I completely missing something? Thanks for the help.

Comment: could you please post proper code? also, i dont see any `json_encode`. Your problem is that your string is empty, but it should be `[]`. if you pass a proper array to json_encode is should always work. but i cant really tell you what you have to do because the code you posted here is messed up

Answer (score 0):

change:

```
var myleaderarray = `<?php echo $myleaderarray; ?>;`
```

to

```
var myleaderarray = "<?php echo $myleaderarray ?>";
```

Comment: quotes aren't really useful here. when it's a string you would have to parse it, but javascript can simply use json values. also, you would need to escape it.

Comment: I tried the double quotes before posting this question and when I do I receive the following SyntaxError: "Expected an identifier but found 'Week_count' instead". Week_count is the first key in the array

Comment: @user2232681 post proper code and you get a proper answer. the first php line is invalid php syntax (fatal error). the first javascript line is invalid too, also a syntax error, so how do you expect anyone to help you? (` are illegal characters in javascript outside strings)

Comment: the single quotes are not in my code, my mistake here.

Comment: @user2232681 well, you said something about json_encode in your question, but i don't see any in your code, i also assume that you dont use it, because json_encode always returns javascript compatible code or it throws an error/warning

Answer (score 0):

```
$myleaderarray =  ['{"Week_count":"3","Userid":"102","Username":"gsd555","MedCondPrimary":"Diabetes"}','{"Week_count":"0","Userid":"216","Username":"gsd3","MedCondPrimary":"Cardiac Respiratory"}'];
$count = count($myleaderarray);   // is now two

JQ
var myleaderarray = <?php var_dump($myleaderarray); ?>; // this passes the       array as expected
console.log(myleaderarray.length);
```